# PHP Runtime notice "Only variables should be passed by reference" keep showing even if ignored

Tags: php

I know how to fix this error but our project has millions of lines of codes so I'm not into fixing every single line where it happens.

And I know it's bad practice but I would just like to ignore these errors from being displayed (and logged). I tried:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)
```

But they still show up. Am I missing something? It says: "Severity: Runtime Notice" So I thought it would be **E_NOTICE** but it isn't. Can't find anything about E_RUNTIME_NOTICE in php's [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) either

Answer (score 0):

Try E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however I do need the warnings to be displayed while hiding the runtime notices